# AWS CloudFront works with HTTP, but HTTPS get error - The request could not be satisfied. CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm triying to serve my server trough AWS CloudFront. But I have some issues.

**Scenario**

- One EC2 instance that is able to serve http and https (TLS 1.2)

  - this site serves a self signed TSL certificate.
- One CloudFront distribution

  - Origin pointing to EC2 with protocol marked as "Match Viewer"
  - Behaviour set to do not cache and Viewer protocol policy- HTTP and HTTPS, Cache Based on Selected Request Headers :All
  - Distribution serving HTTPS with an AWS Signed certificate.

**What happens**

- Acessing EC2 directaly does serve the page with "invalid certificate" (as expected)
- Acessing CloudFront Url works to HTTP pages.
- Acessing CloudFront Url DOES NOT works to HTTPS pages... I got 502 error (CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin.)

**What I expect**

- Acessing CloudFront Url working to HTTPS pages.

What should I do to server my HTTPS content using AWS CloudFront?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront cannot connect to origins with invalid certificates. You have a few options:

1. You can configure your distribution to connect to your backed on http only.
2. Put an ELB/ALB in front of your instance and terminate the TLS on the Balancer. You can use Amazon Certificate manager to create a certificate for free.
3. Purchase a certificate from a 3rd party and use it on your instance.

Comment: So do you only select HTTP only at protocol regarding your 1st option? With the 1st option do you need a load balancer? Also with the 1st option can you include the ACM certificate or can you only do that with option 1?